# How can I access useParams value inside redux selector as ownProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

- I am using "reselect" library in redux to get the data. I wanna get data based on `useParams()` hook and then to pass it inside `mapStatetoProps` as `ownProps` and then to `selectionCollection` function which is a selector and accepts the value of `useParams()`. Apparently, it doesn't recognize the `useParams()` as `ownProps` and eventually returns undefined. btw, If I pass a string inside  `selectionCollection('someString)`, I receive the data but not using `useParams()` hook. I do receive the `useParams value successfully` but can't use it inside `mapStateToProps` which I think is a scope problem. I did define a global variable but didn't work.

`import { connect } from 'react-redux';`.

`import { Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';`

`import { selectCollection } from '../../redux/shop/Shop-selectors';`

```
const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const paramsId = params.collectionId;
  console.log(collection);
  
  return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <p>THis is the collection page for {paramsId}</p>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

//-- If I log the 'paramsId', I get undefined since it's outside the function

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
// here is where I wanna use the paramsId as ownProps
  collection: selectCollection(ownProps.paramsId)(state),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage);
```

Comment: You cant access params that get from useParams hook inside of the component in the mapStateToProps , ownProps send from outside of the component into the mapStateToprops just like the actual component props

Comment: how can I access it in this component since it's not being sent from other component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this in different ways but I suggest you two ways to use a params that comes from useParams Hook and mix it with react redux

1- Create another top level component to get the router params in that and pass them to the CollectionPage component, so in the mapStateToProps you can access those params like this:

```
const TopLevelCollectionPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  <CollectionPage params={params}></CollectionPage>;
};

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <p>THis is the collection page</p>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(ownProps.params.collectionId)(state),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage);
```

2- using react redux hooks to get state inside of your component

```
const CollectionPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const collection = useSelector((state) =>
    selectCollection(params.collectionId)(state)
  );
  //or
  //const collection = useSelector(selectCollection(params.collectionId));
};
```

Comment: Created a top level component and passed the `params` as a pros and worked. Thank you

Comment: You can rewrite the functional useSelector as: `const collection = useSelector(selectCollection(params.collectionId));`

Comment: Thanks @HMR for the comment , Yes it could be written this way, it's just for clarification that I wrote it that way.